# How can I write htaccess to redirect simple URL to equivalent queries inside a subfolder? (with authentication)

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subfolder content in:

```
www.mydomain.com/content
```

Users can log in at this location. I have also created a page that will directly load a content using a PHP page:

```
www.mydomain.com/content/direct.php?direct=<contentid>
```

Users can use the link and share them. However, if the user is not yet authenticated, it should redirect them to the homepage with a message letting them know that they need to log in:

```
www.mydomain.com/content/index.php?error=4
```

I wanted to support simple URLS like:

```
www.mydomain.com/content/direct/<contentid>
```

However, I am getting too many redirects error. May I know how I should write my HTACCESS file?

Here is the HTACCESS I am using currently placed inside the subfolder /content/:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#direct
RewriteRule ^/?direct/([^/d]+)/?$ direct.php?direct=$1 [QSA]

#SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled with was to put the .HTACCESS file in the root instead of the subfolder with the following code

```
RewriteRule ^/?content/([^/d]+)/?$ subfolder/content.php?content=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used [R=301,L] instead since I prefer that the real URL is visible to the user. I only needed the simple URL for easier means to integrate them into existing platforms that do not like query strings.

In content.php I place a redirect to the login page if the user is not authenticated. This prevented the multiple redirect error.